# Bamboo problems with maven release plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin, bamboo

I'm trying to migrate some jobs from jenkins over to bamboo and I'm facing some problems here. Whenever I run the job in bamboo, I get the following errors:

```
build   06-Nov-2013 15:46:08    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:execute-commands (execute-cli) on project standalone-d1: Execution execute-cli of goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:execute-commands failed: Plugin org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:jar:7.4.Final -> org.jboss.as:jboss-as-cli:jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8 -> org.jboss.remotingjmx:remoting-jmx:jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-1 -> org.jboss.remoting3:jboss-remoting:jar:3.2.15.GA-redhat-1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.remoting3:jboss-remoting:jar:3.2.15.GA-redhat-1: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.remoting3:jboss-remoting:pom:3.2.15.GA-redhat-1 from/to apache-repos (http://repository.apache.org): Connection to http://repository.apache.org refused: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
build   06-Nov-2013 15:46:08    [ERROR] 
build   06-Nov-2013 15:46:08    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
build   06-Nov-2013 15:46:08    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
build   06-Nov-2013 15:46:08    [ERROR] 
build   06-Nov-2013 15:46:08    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
build   06-Nov-2013 15:46:08    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
build   06-Nov-2013 15:46:08    [ERROR] 
build   06-Nov-2013 15:46:08    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
build   06-Nov-2013 15:46:08    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :standalone-d1
```

I'm pretty new to that kind of stuff, so I'm not really sure, what information one might need in order to help me solve this problem. Therefore it would be great, if you guys could just tell me, whatever I should add to this post, so that you know, where I might start looking for a solution.

For me it looks like it's missing some dependencies, but I couldn't find any missing artifacts. My colleague said, that it might be a problem with the maven-release-plugin, since he had similar problems earlier. Though they couldn't solve those either, but they were quite sure, that it had something to do with the plugin.

Update:
After adding proxy-information to the `settings.xml`, I now get another error:

```
build   07-Nov-2013 09:17:14    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:execute-commands (execute-cli) on project standalone-d1: Execution execute-cli of goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:execute-commands failed: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
build   07-Nov-2013 09:17:14    [ERROR] "address" => [],
build   07-Nov-2013 09:17:14    [ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
build   07-Nov-2013 09:17:14    [ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
build   07-Nov-2013 09:17:14    [ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out
build   07-Nov-2013 09:17:14    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: The root cause seemed to be caused by this: `to http://repository.apache.org refused: Connection refused -> [He`. It looks you don't have access to the repository (might be proxy problem)?

Comment: Good catch! In fact the server is behind a proxy. I added the proxy-information to the `settings.xml`. Now there's another error, which I've added to my question.

Comment: The error message `JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out` looks your configuration or whatever is wrong or your network has a problem.